# assigning and printing from 2d arrays C

Tags: c

```
/*
Program to calculate trip and plan flights
*/
#define TRIP 6 
#define DEST 1
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int type_num, cont_num, index, i, dest_code, trip_num, row, col;
  int travelint[TRIP][DEST]= {{0}};

  printf("Please enter the number of trips:");
  scanf("%d", &trip_num);
  for (i=0; i < trip_num ; i++)
  {
      printf("Please enter destination code:");
      scanf("%d", &dest_code); 

      cont_num = dest_code / 10000;
      type_num = dest_code/1000 - cont_num*10;

      if ( (cont_num <= 7) && (cont_num > 0) &&  (type_num <= 5) && (type_num >=0) )
          dest_code = travelint[i][0];  
      else
          printf("Invalid code\n");

   }
   printf("%2d", travelint[0][0]);  
   return 0;  
}
```

I'm having trouble printing from the array I'm not sure if I'm either printing it wrong or that the number isn't actually being assign in the array. I'm still having trouble with the concept of assign values from input into the array..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array dimension with only one element in the row is a trifle pointless.  You normally only use dimensions with more than one element in each row.

Additionally, you are never assigning to the `travelint` array - only reading from it.  So, since it is initialized to all zeroes, all you will ever see when you print it are zeroes.

You probably simply need to change this:

```
  if ( (cont_num <= 7) && (cont_num > 0) &&  (type_num <= 5) && (type_num >=0) )
      dest_code = travelint[i][0];
```

to:

```
  if ( (cont_num <= 7) && (cont_num > 0) &&  (type_num <= 5) && (type_num >=0) )
      travelint[i][0] = dest_code;
```

This assigns to `travelint`.

To print out a full 2D array, you would normally use:

```
for (int j = 0; j < TRIP; j++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < DEST; k++)
        printf("Trip[%d][%d] = %d\n", j, k, travelint[j][k]);
}
```

Given that the inner loop will be executed just once per iteration of the outer loop (in your example, where DEST is 1), you could simplify that to:

```
for (int j = 0; j < TRIP; j++)
{
    printf("Trip[%d][%d] = %d\n", j, 0, travelint[j][0]);
}
```

You should validate the `trip_num` after the user enters it.  You should check that `scanf()` actually converted a value; if the user types 'A', then your program will go into a rapid loop printing out "Invalid code" every time.  Always check that inputs succeed.  In theory, you should also check that outputs succeed, but that rule is more often ignored than honoured.  Also, if the user is nasty and types 200, then your program is not going to be happy after the user enters the sixth trip destination.  It should be between 0 and TRIP (inclusive), of course.  You should handle the degenerate (0) case properly, of course.  And the printing loop becomes:

```
for (int j = 0; j < trip_num; j++)
{
    printf("Trip[%d][%d] = %d\n", j, 0, travelint[j][0]);
}
```

Comment: I was trying to load the dest_code next to the Trip_number like trip#1 dest_code = 13453 and printing it back out

Comment: oh okay I think I got the gist of it. Also if I user where to enter a invalid dest_code and I wanted them to re-enter would I put a while loop somewhere along the way?

Comment: @Thao: If you make `travelint` into `int travelint[6][2];`, then you can start from `travelint[0][0]` and also (assuming a round-trip) put it into `travelint[trip_num-1][1]`; you can put subsequent legs of the journey into `travelint[i][1]` and `travelint[i+1][0]` so that each new leg starts where the last left off.  You might want to create `enum { DEP = 0, ARR = 1 };` and use DEP and ARR in expressions such as `travelint[i][ARR]`.

Comment: @Thao: yes, you could have a second loop inside the first, or you can do nasty things like '`i--;`' after the `printf("Invalid code %d\n", dest_code);` statement, remembering to add braces.  Note that the error message should, when possible, reflect the erroneous input from the user so that both you and they know what the computer thought they entered.

Comment: oh okay thankyou for the tips @_@ i think i got the gist of it